# Google App Engine support for utf8mb4

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, emoji, utf8mb4

According to this [article](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/10/29/supporting-new-emojis-on-ios-6), the right way to support emoji characters from iOS4 through iOS6 is to use utf8mb4 encoding. Does App Engine's datastore support utf8mb4? Currently I use the Java version of App Engine as the back end in my iOS app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the article you linked to talks about the writer's experience with developing apps for iOS using `mysql` as the database. In mysql, the encoding "utf8" represents only characters that have 1, 2 or 3 bytes length.

However, utf8 by definition supports 1, 2, 3, or 4 byte long characters. So in the context of mysql encodings and collations, utf8 means characters only upto 3 bytes. For 4 byte long characters, mysql has devised the utf8mb4 encoding.

However, this applies only to the mysql context. Outside of the mysql world, utf8 automatically means support for 1,2,3, or 4 byte characters. See the [UTF-8 wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), it talks about this in the introductory paragraphs:

> UTF-8 encodes each of the 1,112,064[7] code points in the Unicode
>   character set using one to four 8-bit bytes (termed "octets" in the
>   Unicode Standard).

So when a platform or software application claims to support UTF-8, it implies support for all the 1,112,064 code points that can consume 1,2,3, or 4 bytes per character.

The mysql case is an anomaly where the utf8 encoding wasn't really 100% utf8 but only some 6% of utf-8 (but most people wouldn't notice that unless they start using emojis or other characters).

So my suggestion is that it is safe to assume that google app engine supports 4 byte characters when they accept utf-8 as a valid encoding supported by them.